# What does "done" : true value indicates in JSON response

Tags: rest-api, json

I am using Rest API to get the listviews of selected object using following code :

```
Http h3 = new Http();
HttpRequest request1 = new HttpRequest();
request1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+accessToken);
request1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
request1.setHeader('accept','application/json');
request1.setMethod('GET');             
request1.setEndpoint(instanceURL+'/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Lead/listviews');
HttpResponse res1 = h3.send(request1);
```

Response string is :

```
{
    "done":true,
    "listviews":[
        {
            "describeUrl":"/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Contact/listviews/00Bi00000025qFwEAI/describe",
            "developerName":"NewLastWeek",
            "id":"00Bi00000025qFwEAI",
            "label":"New Last Week",             
                         "resultsUrl":"/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Contact/listviews/00Bi00000025qFwEAI/results",
            "soqlCompatible":true,
            "url":"/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Contact/listviews/00Bi00000025qFwEAI"
        },
        {
            "describeUrl":"/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Contact/listviews/00Bi00000025qGjEAI/describe",
            "developerName":"AllContacts",
            "id":"00Bi00000025qGjEAI",
            "label":"All Contacts",         
"resultsUrl":"/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Contact/listviews/00Bi00000025qGjEAI/results",
            "soqlCompatible":true,
"url":"/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Contact/listviews/00Bi00000025qGjEAI"},
        ],
    "nextRecordsUrl":null,
    "size":6,
    "sobjectType":"Contact"
}
```

Here what does "done" : true indicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done: true means salesforce returned all the records for the query fired and there are no more records..If done is false, you will have a non-null value for the property, nextrecordsurl.  Done flag is useful to check if we need to make another query to salesforce to get the remaining records of the query we sent, the reason is if your query returns more than 2000 records, salesforce returns only first 2000 records and sets the done to false also includes the nextrecordsurl.

Comment: So, done can be false even when the status code is 200 ?

Comment: I am not sure..I will make a fake call to see what it responds back with.

Comment: This is true when you query for records. But here I am using listview API.

Comment: The sam logic works in all places where pagination is used. Listview is also kind of pagination so the same rules apply.

Comment: done is false, but I don't see the nextrecordsurl anywhere

Comment: @otonakav You should post this as new question with more details.